# How to overcome spaces in the path while passing to system()?

Tags: c

In the following statement :

```
system("%TESTCASES_PATH%SIP\\test.bat");
```

the %TESTCASES_PATH% gets resolved to "C:\Program Files..." .

As such the result of calling the system is :

"'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command.."

'C:\Program' is thought as a executable..

How to overcome the above issue?

**EDIT:** Trying out what is proposed in the answers, I get to see the same behavior. The following is the actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    system("\"%TESTCASES_PATH%SIP\\Provisioning\\CrHomeDnOfficeCodeDestCodeBySoap\\CreateHomeDnOfficeCode.bat\"");
    //system("\"%TESTCASES_PATH%SIP\\tests.bat\"");
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use double quotes to pass the entire path as the executable / batch file:

```
system("\"%TESTCASES_PATH%SIP\\test.bat\"");
```

Otherwise, what's after a space becomes the first command-line parameter.

EDIT: Perhaps on your setup, `%TESTCASES_PATH%` is not expanded by the `system()` function.  On most systems, you can retrieve the value of an environment variable with `getenv()`:

```
char cmd[FILENAME_MAX];
snprintf(cmd, FILENAME_MAX, "\"%s\\test.bat\"", 
    getenv("TESTCASES_PATH"));
system(cmd);
```

Comment: @Prabhu. S: Maybe you have to expand the environment variable yourself (answer edited)

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
system("\"%TESTCASES_PATH%SIP\\test.bat\"");
```

The additional double quotes in the string allow to pass file names with white space to the system call.

Answer (score 1):

With one caveat to both solutions : test them with a string that contains NO space too.

It might fail on some windows shells.